# Not getting the features of sdk version 15 while using the cutome title bar

Tags: android, custom-titlebar

My applications minSdkVersion is 15. So the buttons in the application will get a light blue color when the user touches it. Later i added a custom title for the application. After that my application components color is changed to orange when the user touches it. I found that it is the problem with the custom title. How to solve it. I need the features of sdk version 15. Please see how i added the custom title bar.

My Manifest.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

My style used for the custome title bar (custom_style.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
            <item name="android:windowTitleSize">30dip</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

Activity code where it changes to the Custome title bar

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
```

My title bar layout(window_title.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="30dip"
android:background="#FF0000" >

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"/>

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/laodAutomatically"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="MirrorLink auto-connect" 
    style="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme should probably inherit from a theme, which is a theme for the SDK 15. There's a nice tutorial that will get you started with supporting various SDK versions with themes and styles. Hope this helps.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Your theme should selectively inherit either Theme, or android:Theme.Light, depending on the platform version. Look towards the end of this page.